# Manipulate Dynamically Generated Elements in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce-id

The below code dynamically generates `<td>` and `<ui:inputText>`. I want to access the `<ui:inputText>` and change its value in the helper. How can I achieve that?

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.comComp}" var="value">
     <td class="slds-truncate">
        <ui:inputText class="slds-input comAmount" type="number" value="{!value.Amount__c}" aura:id="{!value.Id}" />
    </td> 
</aura:iteration>
```

I've tried component.find() but it always returns `Undefined`. Also, whatever the {!value.Id} is, we get something like id="13:596;a" when inspecting the element which does not reflect {!value.Id} value at all!!.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Both of the following options are an approach where you are cherry-picking an input from your markup based off of some known value. Usually the the reason behind targeting a specific input is because an action has been performed on that input, in which case this is done via events on the input itself.

That being said, couple of options here:

**Set the aura:id and domId:**

```
<ui:inputText domId="{!value.Id}" aura:id="comAmount" class="slds-input comAmount" type="number" value="{!value.Amount__c}" />
```

In componentHelper.js

```
var matches = cmp.find('comAmount');
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  if(matches[i].get('v.domId') == "yourValue") {
    // update value here
  }
}
```

**Only set the dom id and fetch in renderer**

```
<ui:inputText domId="{!value.Id}" class="slds-input comAmount" type="number" value="{!value.Amount__c}" />
```

In componentRenderer.js:

```
({
  afterRender : function(component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    var input = document.getElementById("yourValueId");
    helper.processItem(input);
  }
})
```

The second option requires you to do it in your afterRender as the dom may not have rendered yet at the time you are trying to access it in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `aura:id` can't be set dynamically, it has to be a hard coded value.

You could try to dynamically create your component in your JavaScript controller and set the aura:id there, see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm